# Why is my C++ program giving me the wrong output?

Tags: c++

I am attempting to write a C++ program to do the following:

> Calculate the sum of all members of a structure array

This is the code:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct complex
{
    int real;
    int image;
};

int f3(complex a[])
{
    int sum=0,i;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        sum=sum+a[i].real+a[i].image;
    }
    return sum;
} 

int main()
{
    complex z[3]={(1,1),(1,1),(1,1)};
    cout<<f3(z)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The result that I get is `3`, but I was expecting it to be `6`.

Why is the result 3 and not 6?

Comment: `(1,1)` is an comma expression that evaluates to the single value `1`.  To initialize your struct, you need curly braces `{1,1}`.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm that should be posted as an answer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Typo or answer, there's likely a duplicate for this somewhere, but I've moved my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`(1,1)` is an comma expression that evaluates to the single value `1`. To initialize your struct, you need curly braces `{1,1}`.